# Java 8's missing parameters when using ::

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, java-8, method-reference

Java 8's `::` enables method referencing via method name alone.

```
protected Object loadBeanController(String url) throws IOException {
    loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(url));
    ApplicationContext context = MyProjectClass.getApplicationContext();

    loader.setControllerFactory(context::getBean);

    return loader.getController();
}
```

But, however, according to [BeanFactory Interface (Spring) `getBean()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.4/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html) `getBean` does not take empty parameters - Some parameter values are expected:

> getBean(String name)
>   getBean(String name, Class requiredType)
>   getBean(String name, Object[] args)

How is this resolved?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

JavaFX's `FXMLLoader` method [`setControllerFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#setControllerFactory-javafx.util.Callback-) takes a [`Callback`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/Callback.html) as parameter.

This is a functional interface whose sole method is `call` taking one parameter and returning one result. In this case, the type of the argument is `Callback<Class<?>, Object>`. So the lambda expression expects an argument of type `Class<?>`.

So, actually, none of the methods you cited will be called. What will be called is [`getBean(Class<T> requiredType)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean-java.lang.Class-) (this method only exists since Spring 3.0 so you won't see it in your linked 2.5.4 reference).

It is possible to rewrite the method expression like this to make this more clear:

```
loader.setControllerFactory(c -> context.getBean(c));
```

Here, `c` will have the type `Class<?>` because of the declared parameter of `setControllerFactory`.

As a side note, everything will compile because `setControllerFactory` expects the result of the callback to be of type `Object` so the result of `context.getBean(c)` will always match.